# FullCalendar header not displaying buttons and views in Android devices

Tags: jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar in an Android tablet application, which is developed using Oracle Mobile Application Framework.

The mobile page can display a FullCalender object successfully and respond to event selection. The only issue I can see now is that the Header portion of the calendar can only display "title"; it can not render a button for navigating to previous day and next day, nor can it render buttons for switching to different views. This means I cannot navigate to other month or days.

I am using the following versions:

> fullCalendar: 2.4.0,
>   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js,
>   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css,
>   jquery.min.js and moment.js (bundled with the fullCalendar 2.4.0)

Could it be some css classes need to be updated?

The following is the configuration of the Header portion of fullCalendar:

```
calendarElementJQ.fullCalendar(
{ header: { center: 'today prev,next', right: 'title', 
  left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' }, 
defaultDate: '2015-11-07', 
editable: true, 
eventLimit: true, ... ...})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to fix English issues and have formatted and marked down the version list using > and the code using four leading psaces.

Comment: thank you very much. Appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

I "resolved" the issue by removing the "fullcalendar.print.css" from the resources referenced by the mobile page. That is, after removing this css reference, all the header components are rendered and behaved properly in the mobile page.

The only downside after removing the "fullcalendar.print.css" is that the font used for rendering event title does not look nice. What is the CSS class for rendering event title?

thanks

Comment: .fc-event is where it gets most of its font styling defaults. If that's not what you want try .fc-title